# extend sum to dynamic range with excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, sum, autofill

I am trying to extend a sum formula to a dynamic range. The sum includes all values from row 5 till the second last used row in the column, the sum is then in the last used row. However, the number of rows and columns vary, the only thing that stays the same is that the sum should always start in row 5. The sum starts also always in column C. I already managed to write a macro that puts the sum in the last row of column C. I am now working on a macro that extends this sum to all other used columns in the sheet, except for the last column (that contains another value and not a sum).
I am working with selection.autofill. However, I am having issues with declaring the range that i want to fill. VBA gives me an "expected: end of statement" error and I can't figure out why. Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong? Is there a better method than selection.autofill - i fear that it might not take over the columns, e.g. actually summing up column D when extended to the cell in column D ?
Here is what i already have:

```
'
' sumtest Macro
'

'
Dim Cell As Range, sRange As Range
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook
Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")


End With

FirstRow = Rows(5).EntireRow
lastRow = wsDestination.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = wsDestination.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn1 = wsDestination.Cells(4, wsDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Worksheets("Overview").Select
wsDestination.Cells(lastRow, "C").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(C5:C" & lastRow - 1 & ")"
Range(wsDestination.Cells(LastRow1, 3)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(wsDestination.Cells(LastRow1,3),wsDestination.Cells(LastRow1,LastColumn -1)) Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need it to be a formual? Can it just be the value of the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would write the **value** of the sum in each column for the last row:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sumtest()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
        Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim LastRow As Long
        For Each Cell In .Range("C4", .Cells(4, LastCol))
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(LastRow, Cell.Column) = Application.Sum(.Range(Cell.Offset(1), .Cells(LastRow - 1, Cell.Column)))
        Next Cell
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that the code will check the `LastRow` for every column, so if the columns have different amount of rows the total will be on the first row without data for each column.

Comment: Hi Damian, thanks, the code works quite well. I now need to exclude to columns, where the sum is not needed. The position of these columns varies as well, however they contain certain strings in row 4. Can you give me a tip on how to approach this? With an if statement? Should the if statement encapsule the loop or other way around?

Comment: @Meisje17 are there a lot of strings? do they have some common pattern?

Comment: its 2 strings and they are always the same

Comment: @Meisje17 `If Cell = "Your String1" Or Cell = "Your String2" Then GoTo NextCell` and also write a line above `Next Cell` with `NextCell:`